# Migration of positioning code from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have the following code to set the cursor position in a 16bit display:

```
linCursor.x1 = VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(lblDisplay(pintCursorPos).Left) + 10
linCursor.x1 = VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(lblDisplay(pintCursorPos).Left) + 10

linCursor.X2 = VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(lblDisplay(pintCursorPos).Left) + VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(lblDisplay(pintCursorPos).Width) - 10
```

I need this code to be converted to vb.net. Could anyone help me get started?

Comment: I presume these are in different containers as one has twip coordinated, the other is pixels. If not, then it's doing something odd.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest conversion involves just dropping the twips stuff entirely; [those don't exist in the world of .NET](http://visualbasic.about.com/cs/visualbasicfaq/a/dykpixeltwip.htm) where you work directly with pixels.

```
linCursor.x1 = lblDisplay(pintCursorPos).Left + 10
linCursor.x1 = lblDisplay(pintCursorPos).Left + 10

linCursor.X2 = lblDisplay(pintCursorPos).Left + lblDisplay(pintCursorPos).Width - 10
```

Comment: +1 although you might want to change the `10` values to `0` or `1` as they are now in pixels rather than twips. It depends on the screen resolution, but 10 twips is about 0.6 pixels on my screen.

Comment: "X1 is not a member of windows.forms.label" comes into play nw....tell me how to resolve this.